# What is map file in GRASS GIS addon r.fuzzy.system and how it can be accessed?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, fuzzy-logic

I am inexperienced with GRASS GIS and I am trying to reproduce the fuzzy systems manual example. I am failing to load the MAP file, even if I wrote the 'txt' file with the rules and maps name.
Here is the manual example:https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.fuzzy.system.html.

What is a 'MAP file', how can it be accessed, and how do I use it?

Comment: I would not recommend using the GRASS fuzzy system. I believe it is buggy. See http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/r-fuzzy-system-help-with-defuzzification-td5444785.html#a5444896 and https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/issues/176

Comment: Thanks, It would be great to find a similar alternative. One that  I have in mind is to try something in R.

Comment: Read the first link thread. Python has an alternative that works well with GRASS.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual page of r.fuzzy.system](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.fuzzy.system.html) states "Name of fuzzy variable file". It is a kind of control file with a specific structure - simply a text file containing maps name and fuzzy sets connected with map definition. The manual page also offers examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to reproduce the example, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I see an open bug report: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/issues/176